# Wordpress Classic Editor Changed After Changing the theme

Tags: wordpress

Screenshot of the editor with the current theme: https://prnt.sc/OGoHLm7phUDj

Screenshot of the editor with the new theme: https://prnt.sc/bkpOA3vr1DtQ

What should I add in the functions.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did find a solution after a lot of searching and attempts, and I'll post it here for anyone facing the same issue,

```
function my_format_TinyMCE( $in ) {
  $in['plugins'] = 'wpeditimage,wpautoresize,tabfocus,paste,media,fullscreen,wordpress,wpgallery,wplink,wpdialogs';
  $in['toolbar2'] = '';

  return $in;
}

add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', 'my_format_TinyMCE' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another no-code solution. In fact answer of Mohamed El-Azzawy configures the editor.
For no-code fine tunning of WordPress additional plugin could be used: "Advanced TinyMCE Configuration"
In this page
https://bghints.blogspot.com/2023/04/customizing-classical-editor-in-wordpress.html
there is a guide and examples for configuration of plugin and respectively the Classical editor. It includes configuration of buttons.